# Как использовать JOIN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foxpro

Работаю  в visual foxpro. Не работает объединения таблиц, ни через знак равенства ни через `join`.

Вот варианты которые я пробовал:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code_oper FROM car_move WHERE car_move.code_oper = car_oper.code_oper

SELECT DISTINCT code_oper FROM car_move INNER JOIN car_oper ON car_move.code_oper = car_oper.code_oper
```

После выполнения запроса выскакивает такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот значения поля: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во второй таблице все то же самое, только там есть пара новых значений.

Comment: Вам же  пишет в сообщении об ошибке - "CODE_OPER не пойму откуда брать". Подскажите это базе: `SELECT DISTINCT car_oper.code_oper ...`.

Answer (score 1):

в первом запросе в манипулируете двумя таблицами хотя в `from` указывается только одна из них, поэтому СУБД недоумевает, что за второй алиас вы вообще ей указываете.

во втором запросе вы приджойнили вторую таблицу, но тут СУБД недоумевает, столбец из какой из этих таблицы вы пытаетесь выбрать в `select` инструкции. Да они может и имеют одинаковые значения, но в данном случае это не важно, СУБД видит что имя столбца не уникально, о чем вам и говорит в сообщении об ошибке.

> `CODE_OPER` is not uqique and must be qualified.

То есть, повторюсь, имя не уникально, и СУБД просит указать его точнее. То есть просит вас написать либо `car_mode.code_oper` либо `car_oper.code_oper` для уточнения.